# How often do super GMs blunder mate in 1?

Tags: checkmate, statistics, blunder, super-grandmaster

Yesterday (5th April 2023) Nakamura blundered a pretty mate in 1 against Caruana in the Chessable Masters:

```
[Title "Caruana - Nakamura, Chessable Masters 2023"]
[fen "Rb6/5kp1/8/1r1P3P/4p3/B6P/5P2/6K1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Be5 Rf8#
```

Today Maxime Vachier-Lagrave blundered a mate in 1 against Nodirbek Abdusattorov following a blunder a few moves earlier. Here is the sequence starting from when MVL was still level:

```
[Title "MVL - Abdusattorov, Chessable Masters 2023"]
[fen "4rrk1/1p1b2p1/p6p/P1bP3R/2P2p2/2BB4/1P3qPP/R2Q3K w - - 0 1"]

1. Rxh6 gxh6 2. Qh5 Rf6 3. Rf1 Qe3 4. Rf3 Qg1#
```

How often do super GMs, i.e. GMs rated over 2700, blunder in rapid and standard chess?

Note, these games were played with a 15+3 time control, so rapid.

Comment: Not very often I guess 

Comment: Deep Fritz-Kramnik 2006 comes to mind as the most famous example.

Comment: How often do super GMs get struck by lightning in 1?